# android-Include a database at the time of installation

Tags: android

In android, I'd like to include a database at the time of installation i.e. in the .apk file. Is it possible to do that? I have some data in a database that I would want to use in the app. I don't want to use OnCreate method to create a database. So, where should I keep my db file so that it is accessible to the app after installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website helped me out greatly.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I create my SQLite databases separately, add them to the assets directory in the app package, and then on launch of the app copy the databases into the /data/data/com.company.appname/databases/ directory for use there.

I also check to see if the file already exists before bothering to copy it over (so I generally only copy it on first ever launch).

eg

```
boolean createDB= false;

        File dbDir = new File(DB_PATH);
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        if(!dbDir.exists())
        {
            dbDir.mkdir();
            createDB = true;
        }
        else if (!dbFile.exists())
        {
            createDB = true;
        }
```

Comment: will this work if my database has a 10mb size? I mean I need to make app size smaller but if I included it in assets, app size will increase! Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

create your database file, include it in your assets directory and on first launch of your application copy it to /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/